# How to make columns out of unorganized values spread across generic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am somewhat new to T-SQL, and have been tasked with calculating a balance due for customers given an Invoice and a Payments table. Their balance is the sum of their invoiced balances minus the sum of their payments. To complicate matters, each invoiced amount and each payment is split into multiple cost codes. I need to only subtract a payment from the balance of its matching invoice if it has a matching cost code in the invoice. These codes exist in unorganized, generic columns.

A simplified example:

```
-- Invoice table

CustomerID  CaseID    Fee1   FeeAmt1  Fee2    FeeAmt2  ...  FeeN    FeeAmtN
----------------------------------------------------------------
1           51        CODE2  3.00     CODE1   2.00     ...  NULL    NULL
2           55        CODE1  5.00     CODE5   3.00     ...  CODE12  6.00
2           60        CODE2  3.00     CODE3   5.00     ...  NULL    NULL
...
```

```
-- Payments table

CustomerID  CaseID    Fee1   FeeAmt1  Fee2    FeeAmt2  ...  FeeN    FeeAmtN
----------------------------------------------------------------
1           51        CODE5  4.00     CODE2   6.00     ...  NULL    NULL
2           60        CODE1  2.00     CODE4   6.00     ...  NULL    NULL
```

Now you can start to see where it gets complicated:

1. The column names are not indicative of the cost code they contain.
2. The matching column names between the two tables *are not* guaranteed to have the same code in them. In fact the rows my have different sets of cost codes.

#### **My question**: I need help with what I see as step one, which is how to get these tables into this form?

```
-- Payments table

CustomerID  CaseID    CODE1    CODE2  CODE3   CODE4  CODE5 ...  CODEN 
----------------------------------------------------------------
1           51        NULL     6.00   NULL    6.00   4.00  ...  NULL
2           60        2.00     NULL   NULL    6.00   NULL  ...  NULL
```

I am aware that these tables are poorly designed. I have to solve the problem with what I have, unfortunately.

#### EDIT: Additionally it would be helpful if the solution did not require knowledge of the CODE values. i.e. they can be arbitrary and the solution works. I can post another question for that if needed.

Comment: The solution to this is a SQL pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UNION statement to UNPIVOT the data and then use conditional aggregation to get the desired results:

```
;with tableA as
(select 1 as CustomerID,51 as CaseID,'CODE5' as Fee1,4 as FeeAmt1,'CODE2' as Fee2,6 as FeeAmt2,'CODE3' as Fee3,1 as FeeAmt3 union
select 2 as CustomerID,60 as CaseID,'CODE1' as Fee1,2 as FeeAmt1,'CODE4' as Fee2,6 as FeeAmt2,'CODE3' as Fee3,1 as FeeAmt3)

select x.CustomerID,x.CaseID,
--If your CODE number goes to CodeN, add a case statement for each N
       SUM(CASE WHEN x.Code='CODE1' then x.Amount end) as CODE1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN x.Code='CODE2' then x.Amount end) as CODE2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN x.Code='CODE3' then x.Amount end) as CODE3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN x.Code='CODE4' then x.Amount end) as CODE4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN x.Code='CODE5' then x.Amount end) as CODE5
from
--If your fee count goes to FeeN, add a union statement for each N
(select CustomerID,CaseID,Fee1 as CODE,FeeAmt1 as Amount from tableA union
select CustomerID,CaseID,Fee2 as CODE,FeeAmt2 as Amount from tableA union
select CustomerID,CaseID,Fee3 as CODE,FeeAmt3 as Amount from tableA) x
Group by x.CustomerID,x.CaseID
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: If you wanted to dynamically get the code details and the columns, you would have to use Dynamic SQL along with PIVOT function.

**Unpivoting the data:**

```
;with tableA as
(select 1 as CustomerID,51 as CaseID,'CODE5' as Fee1,4 as FeeAmt1,'CODE2' as Fee2,6 as FeeAmt2,'CODE3' as Fee3,1 as FeeAmt3 union
select 2 as CustomerID,60 as CaseID,'CODE1' as Fee1,2 as FeeAmt1,'CODE4' as Fee2,6 as FeeAmt2,'CODE3' as Fee3,1 as FeeAmt3)

select x.*
into #tableB
from
--If your fee count goes to FeeN, add a union statement for each N
(select CustomerID,CaseID,Fee1 as CODE,FeeAmt1 as Amount from tableA union
select CustomerID,CaseID,Fee2 as CODE,FeeAmt2 as Amount from tableA union
select CustomerID,CaseID,Fee3 as CODE,FeeAmt3 as Amount from tableA) x
```

**Dynamic query:**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF(
        (SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(a.Code) 
        FROM #tableB a
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT CustomerID,CaseID, ' + @cols + ' from 
        #tableB x
        pivot 
        (max(Amount) 
            for Code in (' + @cols + ')     
         ) p'

execute(@query)
```

You can modify this to fit your needs. You can do the unpivoting using dynamic sql and UNPIVOT function as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will test this soon. I may just post another question for this, but is there a way to do this if I don't know what the codes are beforehand?

Comment: Maybe dynamic SQL, but its going to get real complicated

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of :/ I have a table of the cost codes but am not sure what to do with them once enumerated.

Comment: I have added an edit highlighting how you can do this by using Dynamic SQL...Hopefully you can take it from here

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by unpivoting the data and repivoting:

```
select coalesce(i.customerId, p.customerId), coalesce(i.caseId, p.caseId),
       nullif(sum(case when vi.code = 'CODE1' then vi.amt else 0) +
              sum(case when vp.code = 'CODE1' then vp.amt else 0), 0),
       nullif(sum(case when vi.code = 'CODE2' then vi.amt else 0) +
              sum(case when vp.code = 'CODE2' then vp.amt else 0), 0),
       . . .
from invoice i cross apply
     (values (fee1, feeamt1), (fee2, feeamt2), . . .
     ) vi(code, amt) full join
     payment p
     (values (fee1, feeamt1), (fee2, feeamt2), . . .
     ) vp(code, amt) 
     on i.customerId = p.customerId and i.caseId = p.caseId
group by coalesce(i.customerId, p.customerId), coalesce(i.caseId, p.caseId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will test this soon. I may just post another question for this, but is there a way to do this if I don't know what the codes are beforehand?

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors with the `(values ...` line after  `payment p`, and on each `)` right after each `else 0`.

Comment: @CollinBrittain . . . This is totally supported by SQL Server, so it is unclear why you would be getting syntax errors.